# How to Return partial view on asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

The following code will not works on server after hosting,but it works fine on localhost. Is there is any problem on code.

**Controllers:**

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult SelectCustomerByID(Receipt model, string secondValue)
        {
            int CustID = 0;
            if (secondValue != null && secondValue != "")
                CustID = Convert.ToInt32(secondValue);
                ObservableCollection<Receipt> ReceiptList = new ObservableCollection<Receipt>();
                Receipt Receipt = new Models.Receipt();
                if (CustID != 0)
                    ReceiptList = Receipt.GetReceiptListByCustID(CustID);
                else
                   ReceiptList = Receipt.GetReceiptList();
                ViewData["Count"] = ReceiptList.Count;
                return PartialView("_Recepitgrid", ReceiptList);            
        }
```

SCRIPT IN PARTIAL VIEW:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var str = ('@ViewData["Count"]');
        if (str == '0')
            ShowProduct();
        else
            ShowGrid();
    });

    function ShowProduct() {
        document.getElementById("gridContent").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("ShowNodata").style.display = 'block';
        return false;
    }
    function ShowGrid() {
        document.getElementById("gridContent").style.display = 'block'; 
        document.getElementById("ShowNodata").style.display = 'none';
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

PartialView:

```
    <div id="divgrid" >
          @{  
           var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
          grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);}
          <div id="gridContent" class="rounded-corners">
           @grid.GetHtml(
           tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
           headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
           footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
           alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
           selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
           rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
           columns: grid.Columns(
           grid.Column(header: "S.No", format: item => Item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item) + 1),
             grid.Column("Recepit_No", "Recepit Number", style: "PName"),
              grid.Column(null, null, format: @<input type="hidden" name="Id"  id="ID" value="@item.ID"/>),
             grid.Column("Cust_Name", "Cust Name", style: "PName"),
            grid.Column("Pay_Amount", "Paid Amount", style: "Curency"),
            grid.Column("Pay_Mode", "Paid Mode", style: "IName"),
            grid.Column("Bank_Name", "Bank Name", style: "Weight"),
             grid.Column("Bank_Address", " Bank Address", style: "MakingCharge"),
             grid.Column("ChequeNo", "ChequeNo", style: "Certification"),
              grid.Column("Cheque_Date", " Cheque Date", style: "Price"),
             grid.Column("Date", "Date", format: item => ((item.Date == null) ? "" : item.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")), style: "Price"),
              grid.Column("Edit", "", @<a href='../Admin/EditReceipt?Id=@item.Id' ><img src="~/Images/edit.png" alt='Edit' /></a>, style: "width:10%"),
             grid.Column(header: "Delete", format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("DeleteReceipt", "Admin", new { Id = item.ID })" onclick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you'd like to delete this product?');"><img src="../Images/delete.png" alt='Delete' /></a></text>)
                                         ))

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) How are you calling the Partial View? If you are referencing a fixed r relative url '../Controller/SelectCustomerByID/blah..' rather than using the @Url.Action helpers this may be the cause. 2) Have you used a web developer plugin (firebug) to see if there are any invalid network connections being attempted.

Comment: `$("#Cust_Id").change(function () {
            firstDDLValue = $("#Cust_Id").val();
            $.get('@Url.Action("SelectCustomerByID", "Admin")', { secondValue: firstDDLValue }, function (ReceiptList) {
                $('#gridContent').html(ReceiptList);
            });
        });`

Comment: i use jqury to call partial view,controller will return to partialview when viewcount becomes zero.

Comment: can you explain exactly what doesn't work means? Is there a server error? Is any of the application working? Can you add some debuging statements to your jquery ajax call to confirm it is working? If its this call that is not working considering adding  .fail(error)  function to provide more info ([jquery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/))

Comment: thanks for your comments..i used the above grid in view also.When user change DDL the values will bind on the grid.It doesn't show any errors .The values will bind when i run this application on Localhost but not works after hosting,

Answer (score 1):

(Offering a series of options as an answer rather than turning into a giant comment spam thread.)

It sounds like your application and logic is fine, but you might be running on a different data source when you move to production.

you make a referece to `var str = ('@ViewData["Count"]');` in the partial view. Add a debug or alert to show what this value actually is. If your published site is showing ViewData["Count"] = 0 then your partial view is just obeying what you are telling it to do.

If you have a valid number in `ViewData["Count"]`, next thing to do is to confirm their is data in your `MODEL`. Trying including some temporary debug statements in your partial view before the grid like this:

```
<span id="debugCheck1">is the model null? = @(Model==null)         </span>
<span id="debugCheck2">Model has this many rows? = @Model.Count  </span>
<div id="divgrid" >
      @{
      ..
```

Finally, get Firefox and install firebug (or any webdeveloper tool for your browser of choice) and use the NET panel to check for any requests showing 404 error. Use it to view the ajax requests and see the actual results being sent.

Good luck.

Comment: thank u @joe. when ViewData["Count"]=0 the controller return to partial view and when ViewData["Count"] has greater than zero it doesn't return to partialview..I check it by set an alert is there is any problem on controller code joe